# Adding https with Godaddy domain & beanstalk environment (ACM)

Tags: godaddy, amazon-elb, elastic-beanstalk

First of all I tried to google, read a lot blogs & aws official documentation and couldn't find anything that works in my case.

Scenario & Problem:

I have a godaddy domain and a beanstalk environment. Also, I issued ACM certificate and assigned it to beanstalk through configuration. I can see the issued certificate in loadbalancer attached to beanstalk env. I have setup (godaddy) A record to elastic IP of my beanstalk instance & www to beanstalk dns x.us-west-2.beanstlak.com. Http is working absolutely fine. But no luck with https.

Loadbalancer Listener:

```
HTTPS   443 HTTP    80  Change  07xxaab5-afqq-4tyb-bbz-0eaxxxw37 (ACM)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not direct requests to your EB instance - it all needs to go through your load balancer. It's your load balancer that is configured with your cert.

Comment: I have load balancer attached to beanstalk environment. (through configuration -> HTTPS -> 443). So, when I open mydomain.co.uk shouldn't it hit my elastic IP, which has a load balancer attached...right?

Comment: Wrong. Your EIP has nothing to do with your load balancer.

Comment: its not an old balancer. I created a complete new load balancing environment. After successful launch, i went to configuration of beanstalk environment to set HTTPS (443) then selected my pre-issued ACM certificate for domain. Also you can check the loadbalancer listener i updated in question.

Comment: Sorry, "old" was a typo. Again, your requests need to be directed to the address of your load balancer, not your EIP.

Comment: i see. So you meant to say that I shouldn't add x.us-west-1.beanstalk.com on WWW record of godaddy domain? And instead of A name record (currently elastic IP) what should I add? (because godaddy A name record should be an IP)

Comment: Your domain needs to point to the host name of your load balancer. This can either be a CNAME or Alias record. I don't believe GoDaddy supports Alias records, though.

Comment: the simple question here is If i cannot use elastic IP as A name record on godaddy domain...Which IP can I use? I mean as per my understanding, there is no IP attached to load balancer. As you know Godaddy domain only accepts IPs instead of dns or hostnames

Comment: Then you'll need to change DNS providers. Plain and simple, you cannot directly use an IP with ELB.

Comment: GoDaddy is a horrible company anyway. They don't deserve your business.

Comment: I agree. But currently I am bound to use godaddy domain.

Comment: Well then it's not going to work for you.

Comment: So, I assume there is no way to use beanstalk environment & ACM with godaddy domain.

Comment: It can work with www.example.com, because that can be a CNAME record. It will never work with your zone apex, though.

Comment: the funny thing is it was working before on a single instance with letsencrypt certificate & godaddy domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To synthesize an answer based on the comment thread:

Usage of ELB requires that you can point your DNS names to the ELB via either `CNAME` or `Alias` (`ANAME`) records. You *cannot* use `A` records with ELB.

If you are using a DNS provider that does not support `Alias` record types, you will not be able to point your zone apex (e.g. `example.com`) to your ELB. In this situation, you still **are** able to point other names, such as `www.example.com` to the ELB, as that can be a `CNAME` record, which all providers support.

---

Your setup is currently working just fine with HTTPS **except** for the fact that `www.legitclaims.co.uk` is not listed as a valid name on your certificate. Only `legitclaims.co.uk` is:

[image]

Comment: okay. putting awseb-e-g-AWSEBLoa-xxxxx-xxxxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com WWW record in godaddy should work..right ?

Comment: Yes, that should work, as a `CNAME` record.

Comment: awesome! If it works I can redirect to www. let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Well, you need to serve your zone apex with HTTPS as well (if even just to do the redirect), which you can't do with your current DNS situation.

Comment: I switched my x.us-west-2.beanstalk.com to awseb-e-g-AWSEBLoa-xxxxx-xxxxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com as CNAME WWW record. I am not sure how much time it takes to update records. But getting not secure with https on https://www.mydomain.co.uk

Comment: Well, without knowing the hostname in question, there's nothing more I can do to help.

Comment: here you go: 

Domain: https://www.legitclaims.co.uk/
ELB: awseb-e-g-AWSEBLoa-OKJM2PEUYJE3-1375367985.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com

Comment: Please see my updated answer - you need to correct the valid hostnames for your certificate.

Comment: You can add both hostnames to your ACM cert if you'd like. That way you can use the cert for both once you move away from GoDaddy.

Comment: Thank you...Its working now. The point was to issue certificate for www.mydomain.com in my case instead of domain.com.
If possible you can update answer with this. 

Thank you once again and have a nice day :)